# Getting number of features in the Attribute table using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, features, count

I have a layer and I would like to access the number of rows the attribute table has from my code. Is there a way to do that without doing it like this:

```py
num_of_features = 0

for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    num_of_features += 1

print(num_of_features)
```

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 16):

Yes, there is a direct way to access the number of rows of your attribute table. Just call [`featureCount()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a9ef4be45569d3875ba6b071bdd54edaf) method from your `layer` object:

```py
num_of_features = layer.featureCount()
```

Answer (score 6):

[`layer.getFeatures()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ab0aee12fd9ff7c20b6587d6019f19edc) is a Python [Iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) (type: `QgsFeatureIterator`) so

```py
num_of_features = len(list(layer.getFeatures()))
```

or you can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
num_of_features = len([feature for feature in layer.getFeatures()])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option can be the [`allFeatureIds()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureSource.html#ac25a91ac31808a8dc2b76026870fcf8b) method from the `QgsFeatureSource` class:

```py
num_of_features = len(layer.allFeatureIds())
```